# CakePHP Database Query Count(Case When)

Tags: mysql, database, cakephp, count

I'm using CakePHP and cannot seem to translate this SQL query I did on the workbench. It's exactly what I want to do but I cannot seem to make it work.

This is my query on MySQL:

```
select
    docs.id, docs.schoolId, schools.name, docs.datesubmitted, docs.status,
    uploads.iddocs,
    COUNT(*),
    COUNT(case uploads.staff_checked when 1 then 1 else null end)
FROM
    docs as docs, schools as schools,
    uploads as uploads
where
    docs.schoolId = schools.schoolId AND
    docs.id = uploads.iddocs AND
    docs.status ="Submitted"
group by
    docs.id;
```

What I need to do is combine three tables: Docs, Schools, and Uploads.

The two counts: `COUNT(case when)` and `COUNT(*)` indicate the number of documents reviewed (`COUNT(case when)`) and total documents needed to be reviewed (`COUNT(*)`).

So far MySQL is showing what I need. Can someone figure out how to do it in Cake?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query

```
$this->virtualFields = array(
    'count_case_uploads_staff_checked_when_1_then_1_else_null_end' => 'COUNT(case uploads.staff_checked when 1 then 1 else null end)',
    'count' => 'COUNT(*)',
);
$options = array(
    'fields' => array(
        'Doc.id',
        'Doc.schoolId',
        'schools.name',
        'Doc.datesubmitted',
        'Doc.status',
        'uploads.iddocs',
        'Doc.count_case_uploads_staff_checked_when_1_then_1_else_null_end',
        'Doc.count',
    ),
    'joins' => array(

        array(
        ),
    ),
    'conditions' => array(
        'Doc.schoolId = schools.schoolId',
        'Doc.id = uploads.iddocs',
        'Doc.status' => 'Submitted',
    ),
    'group' => array(
        'Doc.id',
    ),
);
$data = $this->find('all', $options);
```